# NodaTime ZoneIntervals

Tags: nodatime

I'm attempting to build a logical set of time zone records representing a 5-year period where the stop and start date/time matches to what a person perceives as the time change moment daylight savings is observed.  For example, in America/New_York id, I want:

```
03/13/2016 2:00 am    -   11/06/2016  01:59:59 am  gmtOffset:  -4:00
11/06/2016 2:00 am    -   03/12/2017  01:59:59 am  gmtOffset:  -5:00
```

I am able to build these records, but I see no other way than to start prior to 1912 when dst went in effect and track the End Instant for all zone intervals.  I don't see a way to determine the offset in effect when an Interval record period begins other than the previous Interval record.  Is there a way to do this using just a single ZoneInterval record?

Question noted in code:

```
    private void processTZ()
    {
        IDateTimeZoneProvider provider = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb;

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\tzOut.txt"))
        {
            foreach (string id in provider.Ids)
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Id: {0}", id);
                DateTimeZone zone = provider[id];

                // Time period I wish to create logical representation.
                Instant instantValidityBegin = (new LocalDateTime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0)).InZoneLeniently(zone).ToInstant();
                Instant instantValidityEnd = (new LocalDateTime(2019, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 0)).InZoneLeniently(zone).ToInstant();

                // Time period from zone intervals to iterate. The first year dst was observed was 1916.
                Instant instantFetchYearBegin = (new LocalDateTime(1916, 1, 1, 0, 0)).InZoneLeniently(zone).ToInstant();
                Instant instantFetchYearEnd = (new LocalDateTime(2019, 12, 31, 23, 59, 0)).InZoneLeniently(zone).ToInstant();

                // Get the intervals
                IEnumerable<NodaTime.TimeZones.ZoneInterval> intervals = zone.GetZoneIntervals(instantFetchYearBegin, instantFetchYearEnd);

                // Determine number of intervals for this tzId.
                int count = 0;
                foreach (NodaTime.TimeZones.ZoneInterval zi in intervals)
                    count++;

                bool singleEntry = (1 == count);

                // myStart and myEnd are desired output period
                // capture IsoLocalEnd of an interval to be used as the start date of program output (myStart).  Don't display older than 1900.
                DateTime myStart, myEnd, prevEnd = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);

                foreach (NodaTime.TimeZones.ZoneInterval zi in intervals)
                {
                    if (singleEntry)
                    {
                        // No question here
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // skip intervals for this tzId that represent a period beginning after time period I want.
                        if (instantValidityEnd < zi.Start)
                            break;

                        // Skip intervals ending prior to time period I want, but capture the IsoLocalEnd to be used for report output.
                        if (zi.End < instantValidityBegin)
                        {
                            prevEnd = (zi.End == Instant.MinValue) ? prevEnd = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1) : prevEnd = zi.IsoLocalEnd.ToDateTimeUnspecified(); ;
                            continue;
                        }

                        //   ***Question***  Can this myStart value be determined using the current interval record instead of storing the previous interval's IsoLocalEnd??
                        myStart = prevEnd;
                        if (zi.End == Instant.MaxValue)
                            prevEnd = myEnd = new DateTime(9999, 12, 31);
                        else
                        {
                            prevEnd = zi.IsoLocalEnd.ToDateTimeUnspecified();
                            myEnd = prevEnd.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));  // force period back 1 second for logical representation.
                        }


                        sw.WriteLine("Name: " + zi.Name);
                        sw.WriteLine("Multi Entry: {0}", zi.ToString());
                        sw.WriteLine("myStart: {0:G}   myEnd: {1:G}    gmtOffset: {2:G}", myStart, myEnd, zi.WallOffset.ToTimeSpan());
                        sw.WriteLine();
                    }
                }

                sw.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------");
                sw.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: To be more precise, the start time of an interval is "off" by the dst amount of the previous record; however, the previous end record stores the time needed for this type of logical representation.

Comment: [The docs for `ZoneInterval`](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/?topic=html/Properties_T_NodaTime_TimeZones_ZoneInterval.htm) has  a comment about `IsoLocalEnd` not including the saving. However, it's unclear if you're using this, or if you're using the `Start` and `End` instants and converting them. Could you please edit your question to show the code you currently have?  We can probably help you easier if you do.  See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: "I don't see a way to determine the offset in effect on a ZoneInterval record" - That's what `WallOffset` is for. Beyond that, I'm having trouble understanding your question I'm afraid.

Comment: @MattJohnson: That "This does not include any daylight saving" comment is a really weird one. Will look into that...

Comment: My apologies Matt and Jon for asking such a confusing question without originally including code example.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I still don't really understand what your code is trying to do - or why you're asking for one set of zone intervals but then filtering to a different range. I've answered the part about determining the offset in a `ZoneInterval` - and I guess you probably want `zi.IsoLocalStart` for `myStart`. Finally, it's not clear why you're using `DateTime` at all - there's less room for error if you just stick to the Noda Time types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On any given `ZoneInterval` record, the `IsoLocalStart` and `IsoLocalEnd` are relative to that particular interval, using the same `WallOffset` value for both.

If you want to get the actual local time in effect you can take the `Start` and `End` instants and convert them to the specific time zone.

```
zi.Start.InZone(zone)
zi.End.InZone(zone)
```

You'll find that the `LocalDateTime` of the starting value matches `IsoLocalStart`, but the ending value does not.  By the time that instant is observed, it is now in covered by the offset of the next interval.   Don't forget that these are *half-open* intervals.  `[inclusive-start, exclusive-end)`.

Let's go back to the example in your original request:

> ```
> 03/13/2016 2:00 am    -   11/06/2016  01:59:59 am  gmtOffset:  -4:00
> 11/06/2016 2:00 am    -   03/12/2017  01:59:59 am  gmtOffset:  -5:00
> ```

It doesn't actually work like that.  In March, the local time moves from `1:59:59 am` to `3:00:00 am`, skipping over an hour.  So the first row should start at `3:00 am` rather than `2:00 am`.  In November, the local time moves from `01:59:59 am` to `1:00:00 am` repeating an hour.  So the second row should start at `1:00 am` rather than `2:00 am`.  Your chart seems to be attempting to make local time continuous - which it is not.

Additionally, you'll find that by convention many people think about the time of the transition as being 2:00, rather that 1:59:59.  Think of it as *approaching* 2:00.  This is why `IsoLocalEnd` is presented with the offset of the current interval, and you could use that field for such a purpose.

Also, you may want to check out [how timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/new-york) shows it.  They've decided to only show the ending values, which may make things a bit clearer.

Comment: Yes, continuous local time is needed.  My company accepts world wide travel schedules and builds customized trips handling connection points for periods greater than a year.  Output is in terabytes and exponential to the number of input records.  A single input record may represent several years of a flight/train/ship schedule offering departing/arriving at a "constant time".  For accurate output, the pgm must analyze the constant time and interpolate (grrrrrrr).  Thanks for you thorough answer!

Comment: Continuous local time is not reality.  See the charts in the [dst tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info).  This is why Noda Time has `InZoneLeniently` and related methods.  However, you'll probably find in practice that travel departure times are usually not scheduled near DST transitions.  Arrival times might be though.  Use departure time + duration to validate the arrival time.